# Downloading plugin C# 5.3.2 from SonarSource site throws an error

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I was trying to download latest C# plugin from http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin. But it thrown an error as access is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You must have issues with your proxy / firewall because I've tested to download it from various IP and everything is working perfectly.